# Sum of absolute values of coefficients of an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x =√2+√5$ is a root of $kx^4+mx^3+nx^2+l = 0$ where $k, m, n, l$ are integers
find the value of $|k| + |m| + |n| + |l|$.

Now as all coefficients are integers, so conjugate of x is also a root of the above.
So putting $x=√2+√5$ and $x=√2-√5$ in the above eq one by one and then subtracting the two equations we got.
We get $k.52.√10 + m.22.√5+ n.4.√10+l=0$

Now $m=0$ and $l=0$ for it to become integer.
and $k.52.√10+ n.4.√10=0$
$\implies n=-13k$
Now putting all values in the original equation
we get $kx^4-13kx^2=0 \implies x^2(kx^2-13k)=0 $ and for x not equal to 0
we get $kx^2-13k=0\implies k=0$ is the only integer solution
Hence $k=l=m=n=0$
hence final answer becomes $0$
Is this the correct way to deduce the problem?
One other way is below

$x =√2+√5 $

$⇒ x−√2 = √5 $

$⇒ (x−√2)^2 = (√5)^2 $

$⇒ x^2+2−2√2x =5 $

$⇒ (x^2 − 3) = 2√2x $

$⇒ (x^2 − 3)^2 = (2√2x)^2 $

$⇒ x^4 − 6x^2 + 9 = 8x^2 $

$⇒x^4 − 14x^2 + 9 = 0 $

$⇒ k = 1, m = 0, n = −14, l = 9 $

$⇒ |k| + |m| + |n| + |l| =1 + 0 + 14 + 9 = 24
$

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't sound right. Note that
$$x^2 = (\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5})^2 = 7 + 2\sqrt{10}.$$
Thus
$$(x^2-7)^2 = 40.$$
It follows that $x$ is a root of the polynomial
$$p(x) := x^4 - 14x^2 + 9,$$
in which case you would have $|k|+|m|+|n|+|l| = 24$. That said, clearly every integer multiple of $p$ also works, so your question is not well-posed.

Comment: This means that there can be multiple answer to the question??

Comment: Should it be 8 instead of 24??

Comment: Positive multiples...

Comment: @FriedSpies How did you come up with $8$? $1 + 14 + 9 = 24$.

Comment: @FriedSpies I just noted your edit to the question. You made an error missing an $x$ when you expanded $(x - \sqrt{2})^2$.

Comment: yes that was a blunder

Answer (score 2):

$x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}$ is a root of the equation
$$Nx^4-14Nx^2+9N=0$$
for any integer $N\neq 0$. Because, $(x^2-7)^2-40= x^4-14x+9=0.$

So, the sum asked can be $24|N|=24M$ for some positive integer $M$.

It can not be zero.